# Firebase fetch function return value local variable issue

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I want to assign a value to a variable inside firebase fetch function. But i get the error "can't find 'count' in scope". I don't want to create a state variable in the view, because i plan to use the function in a foreach loop; and if i return and assign the value to a state variable, the view refreshes each time the value changes. Which means i get flickering number values in the view.

```
func getUnreadMessages(name: String) -> Int{
    guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else {return 0}
    
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("chats").document(name).collection("messages").whereField("read", isEqualTo: false).getDocuments { (snapshot, _) in
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({ $0.documentID }) else {return}
        
        let count = documents.count
    }
    return count
}
```

My question is, how to return a value locally based on the example above?

Comment: The database query works asynchronously. You cannot `return` something, you have to add a completion handler

Comment: Can i use a completion handler and parameter at the same time?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can use as many parameters as you like.

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't convert the function above into a one with completion handler. Any help is appreciated, i have been trying for hours now.

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+completion). This is a quite frequently asked question.

Comment: I am with @vadian - this question has been asked a bunch of times and there are a LOT of examples here on SO. That being said, it looks like you're attempting to get the count of the number of documents in a collection. Instead of reading in all of those documents, I would suggest storing the count in a separate node and as documents are added or removed, increment/decrement the count in that separate node - do it within a transaction so it's always correct. That will be faster, better, and cost less.